# Cross Domain Tracking with new gtag.js framework

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We have a few questions related to the new gtag google analytics tracking code in relation to the cross-domain bi-directional auto linker. In there documentation, they mention you can use one line of code across all sites with unknown origin using the following code,

[Documentation for Cross Site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain)

> To simplify bi-directional cross-domain tracking further, you can list
>   all possible domains you want to track in the domains property of the
>   linker parameter of property's config for each domain, allowing you to
>   use the same snippet of code on every domain:
>
> On example-1.com, update the property's config:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID_1', {
  'linker': {
    'domains': ['example-1.com', 'example-2.com']
  }
});
On example-2.com, update the property's config:

gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID_2', {
  'linker': {
    'domains': ['example-1.com', 'example-2.com']
  }
});
```

1. There are some inconsistencies in this code, for one, it shows the example-1 and example-2 as using different GA_TRACKING_ID's while all the other examples on the page show the same GA TRACKING ID being used across snippets. We need to use the same piece of code, not multiple pieces. We currently are looking to use this method with ONE gtag code across all sites, not multiple gtag snippets as shown. If you reference the other examples in the link above, you will see they also use one gtag.
2. We have a situation where we require access to a 3rd site for cross-domain tracking, but the company will not be able to immediately give us access. We do not want to make multiple requests to website #2, so in the meantime can we add all three websites into our cross-domain linking? Will it cause a conflict to add a third website that is not actively tracking basically, but eventually will be added into the mix
3. Google's old documentation mentions the ability to add more than three domains, does the new gtag framework still have this ability and will it work bidirectionally.
4. I would assume the proper method of adding bi-directional tracking would be to add it as followed to all sites

   gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID_1', {
     'linker': {
       'domains': ['example-1.com', 'example-2.com', 'example-3.com']
     }
   });

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar dilemma reading through the docs and implementing the solution. 
A better step by step overview, that includes a link to the docs you have referenced in your question, is this [Cross domain tracking with gtag.js](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7476333?hl=en)

Code that worked in my case, and that I will mention in my answer bellow, was implemented for a situation where I needed to implement Bi-directional cross-domain tracking across multiple domains. Some of the domains that also needed to be tracked where actually sub-domains (subdomain.example.com), for them you just need to include the root domain (example.com) in the linker parameter domains property array.
Example:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
    'linker': {
        'domains': ['example.com', 'second-example.com', 'third-example.com']
    }
});
```

And the complete code, including the script src tag if someone needs it:

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
    'linker': {
        'domains': ['example.com', 'second-example.com', 'third-example.com']
    }
});
</script>
```

To answer your questions:

1. You need/have to use one Tracking ID (also known as Property ID). That example snippet confused me as well. But you need to use the same Tracking ID as it gathers data to a single property, and that's what you want with cross-domain tracking. More about Properties [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649554?hl=en).
2. I don't see a problem with adding the third website domain to the domains array. The gtag tracking code gets activated only when there is a user on the website where the code is implemented. So in your case, Google Analytics just won't be able to track the traffic on the third domain until you add the appropriate code to it. The tracking on the first two websites where the code IS implemented won't be affected by this.
3. Yes it will work. Working example displayed above this list.
4. Yes, that is correct. But you've also included that extra numbering after the Tracking ID in your example that got us both confused initially :)

Of course this isn't all you need to do in order to setup a correct cross-domain tracking. As mentioned in the document referenced at the top of my answer you will also need to:

- Create a copy of the reporting views and add a custom filter if you want to get full domain names in your reports. It's easier to differentiate the visits between domains this way (example: you may have an about-us.html page on every domain).
- It's **important** that you add the tracked domains to the Referral Exclusion List. If you don't do this, **cross-domain tracking will not work**. It will register a single visitor going from the second-example.com to example.com as a new session.

Extra tip from the docs, that proved really helpful:
For quick testing of the above setup, you can use a Chrome extension developed by Google called "Google Tag Assistant". 
It saved me a lot of time in debugging the issues. 
Especially useful when working on live sites with a lot of traffic. [About Tag Assistant Recordings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6277302)

Comment: are u sure about using the same Tracking id? If so, how would  I differ between the properties?

Comment: @yuria Well in this case (Cross Domain Tracking) you have to use the same Tracking ID in order for everything to work properly.

After you've configured everything per Google analytics instruction docs, you'll see full URLs in your reports. Will that suffice in your use case?